# Blender particles not rendering as in viewport (All dynamics baked)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, particles, baking

I created a particle system, I baked all the dynamics but on render all of the particles are at the origin and I have no idea why.

[image: Particles in the viewport]

[image: Particles in the render]

Here's the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TNl85r53tX-Dx5dGOpyS-yCLtCPgQDxB/view?usp=sharing